# Double Printing of Data

Tags: java

I am writing a program to print the area and perimeter of a rectangle when a user provides the length and width. The user is asked to input how many rectangles he/she wants and then I use a for loop to ask for the length and width, which loops based on the number of rectangles the user inputed.

It prints and works like I want it to ... however, when the user chooses to continue and create more rectangles, the program will print the results of the old data plus the new data instead of just printing the new data.

I am very new to programming in Java and am stuck on how to fix this. It would be great if someone could help me out. Thanks!

This is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class RectangleProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String defaultRectangleOutput = "";
       String newRectangleOutput = "";
       String finalOutput = "";

       int option = JOptionPane.YES_OPTION; 

       while (option == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

          String rectangleNumberString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
             "How many rectangles would you like to create? ",
             "Number of Rectangles", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

             if (rectangleNumberString == null) return;

             while (rectangleNumberString.equals("")) {

             rectangleNumberString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                "You have entered nothing.\n" +
                "Please try again: ");
             }

            int rectangleNumber = Integer.parseInt(rectangleNumberString);

            while (rectangleNumber <= 0) {
               rectangleNumberString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
               "Entry cannot be 0 or negative.\n" +
               "Please try again: ");

               if (rectangleNumberString == null) return;

               rectangleNumber = Integer.parseInt(rectangleNumberString);
             }


             for (int i = 0; i < rectangleNumber; i++) {

             String lengthString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
             "Enter Length for rectangle: ",
             "Getting Length", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

             if (lengthString == null) return;

             while (lengthString.equals("")) {

                lengthString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                   "You have entered nothing.\n" +
                   "Please try again: ");
             }

             double length = Double.parseDouble(lengthString);

             while (length < 0) {
                lengthString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                "Negative numbers are not allowed.\n" +
                "Please try again: ");

                if (lengthString == null) return;

                length = Double.parseDouble(lengthString);
             }

             String widthString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
               "Enter Width for rectangle: ",
               "Getting Length", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

             if (widthString == null) return;

             while (widthString.equals("")) {

                widthString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                   "You have entered nothing.\n" +
                   "Please try again: ");
             }

             double width = Double.parseDouble(widthString);

             while (width < 0) {
                widthString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                  "Negative numbers are not allowed.\n" +
                  "Please try again: ");

                if (widthString == null) return;

                width = Double.parseDouble(widthString);
             }

             SimpleRectangle newRectangle = new SimpleRectangle(width, length);
             newRectangleOutput += "Rect-" + i + " (" + newRectangle.width +
                ", " + newRectangle.length + ")\n" + 
                "Area = " + newRectangle.getArea() + "\n" +
                "Perimeter = " + newRectangle.getPerimeter() + "\n";

             }

             SimpleRectangle defaultRectangle = new SimpleRectangle();

             defaultRectangleOutput = "Default (" + defaultRectangle.width +
                ", " + defaultRectangle.length + ")\n" + 
                "Area = " + defaultRectangle.getArea() + "\n" +
                "Perimeter = " + defaultRectangle.getPerimeter() + "\n";     

             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, defaultRectangleOutput + "\n"
             + newRectangleOutput, "Final Results",
             JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

             option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                null, "Would you like to create another rectangle?");

      }

    }

}

class SimpleRectangle {

  double length;
  double width;

  SimpleRectangle() {
     length = 1;
     width = 1;
  }

  SimpleRectangle(double newLength, double newWidth) {

      length = newLength;
      width = newWidth;
  }

  double getArea() {

      return length * width;
  }

  double getPerimeter() {

      return (2 * (length + width));
  }

  void setLengthWidth(double newLength, double newWidth) {
      length = newLength;
      width = newWidth;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending your new rectangles to the same string. Add `newRectangleOutput = "";` in the while loop before your for loop for all rectangles

```
while (option == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    .
    .

    newRectangleOutput = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < rectangleNumber; i++) {
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You call

```
newRectangleOutput += "Rect-" + ...
```

which is equivalent to

```
newRectangleOutput = newRectangleOutput + "Rect-" + ...
```

So you *add* the output of the new rectangle the the old ones. Replace `+=` by `=`, that is what you want.

Comment: Replacing `+=` by `=` will just display the details for last rectangle. The variable `newRectangleOutput` needs to be re-initialized.

Answer (score 0):

check out what you did here...

```
newRectangleOutput += "Rect-" + i + " (" + newRectangle.width +
            ", " + newRectangle.length + ")\n" + 
            "Area = " + newRectangle.getArea() + "\n" +
            "Perimeter = " + newRectangle.getPerimeter() + "\n";
```

you added the newRectangleOutput to the string again..that's why u re seeing the previous value...

to fix it...before you start with the next rectangle i.e end of each loop... make sure you set `newRactangleOutput = "";`